# A place for developers to post quick tips/lessons learned and tutorials

Tags: feature-request

I'm a huge fan of StackOverflow.com, but it seems like there should be a related site where developers can post quick tips or lessons learned.  There are many time when I have searched the web and stackoverflow for information on a particular topic or problem I need to solve and have come up empty.  In those time, I have to work at the problem until I solve it.  It would be nice if there was a simple place for me to create a post explaining how to solve the problem without having to post to a forum or start my own blog.  Specifically, it would be a lot like the existing stackoverflow.com, but without the requirement of an initial question.  Instead, developers could post quick tips, lessons learned and tutorials that the community could vote on like they do on stackoverflow.com.

I know posting a question then answering it myself is a possibility on stackoverflow.com. I was just thinking it might be nice to have a companion site related to stackoverflow.com where we as a community could post helpful tutorials for problems we recently had to solve. The site could act as a single blog where all readers could easily be authors, too. It could be a place where we could provide more comprehensive details for solving larger problems than we typically see on stackoverflow.com.

Also, the posts would have to solve a specific problem and not be theory or opinion based.  And we could up/down vote posts like stackoverflow.com.

An example of the kind of post that comes to mind might be something like...

Microsoft releases a new version of OData support via the Web Api.  Searching the web only seems to show the greenfield development path, but many users need to know how to convert their existing web api project to support the new release.  Given that I just went through the process of figuring this out, I'd like to share it with the community.  It's not really the typical short-ish answer you'd see on stackoverflow, and it's not really the size of a typical blog post.  It's something in between.  The kind of thing many companies internally use a tool like Confluence to post these brief tutorials on.

Comment: Why didn't you add that final twist to your question on MSO?

Comment: Figured this was a more appropriate place for the question.

Answer (score 4):

As you've already mentioned you can do this already. There's no need to have anything running along side the main site to facilitate this.

As long as your question isn't too broad and open-ended you can self answer at the same time you post your question. So in your example of Microsoft releasing a new version of OData you'd post something like this as your question:

> How do I convert *this* to the new version of OData?

(Where *this* is something specific).

and something like this as your answer:

> You change all the X's to Y's, run this conversion tool and Bob's your Uncle